# Export DXF Issue in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, utm, dxf, nad83

I got the shapefiles in QGIS and transformed them to UTM NAD83 from WGS84, then tried to create a DXF of it so I could use it as an overlay in fieldgenius software for a topographic survey we're conducting. But the DXF created falls wayyyyy on the other side of the world compared to the partial survey I've already done in UTM NAD83. I tried using the DXF file back into QGIS and does the same.
It's my first time experimenting with it, does it lose it's coordinate system information? How can I bring back to right system?

Answer (score 2):

I found that for a successful dxf export you must not enable 'on the fly' reprojection in order to have a project crs different from the data. The project has to have the same crs as your data. cp this issue: [QGIS 2.14.3 export PostGIS layer to dxf issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194914/qgis-2-14-3-export-postgis-layer-to-dxf-issue)

two tickets are on the way concerning the same issues:

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14940

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11988

the later of which describes what you have observed.